# How can I make an array in python whose elements are 2 array

Tags: python, arrays

I am doing a classification problem. My training set is `X_train` containing `60000` elements and each element has `784` features (basically the intensity of pixels of an image). I want to reshape the images in a `28 * 28` array and store them in another array. I tried but can't find a solution. How can I do that?

```
for x in range(60000):
    X_new=X_train[x].reshape(28,28)

len(X_new)
```

I expect `len(X_new) be 60000` but its length is showing as 28.

Comment: I've seen this error too many times (overwriting a variable each time instead of appending to a list), but this might be the purest example. I wonder if there is a duplicate I can point people to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without context, both other answers might be right. However, I'm going to venture a guess that your `X_train` is already a `numpy.array` with shape `(60000, 784)`. In this case `len(X_train)` *will* return `60000`. If so, what you want to do is simply:

```
X_new = X_train.reshape((-1, 28, 28))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `X_train[x]` instead of `X_new`:

```
for x in range(60000): X_train[x] = X_train[x].reshape(28,28)
```

otherwise, `X_new` will store only the last element of the list. You can create a new array if you do not want to spoil the old one:

```
X_new = [X_train[x].reshape(28,28) for x in range(60000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you mean to do this:

```
X_new = []
for x in range(60000):
    X_new.append(X_train[x].reshape(28, 28))

len(X_new)
```

You can also use a list comprehension

```
X_new = [x.reshape(28, 28) for x in X_train]
```